# android opposite of bringChildToFront

Tags: android, android-view

is there a method which does the opposite of bringChildToFront. I want to send the child to back. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method in native android API. But you can implement it by yourself, here is an example:

```
public void moveChildToBack(View child) {
    int index = indexOfChild(child);
    if (index > 0) {
        detachViewFromParent(index);
        attachViewToParent(child, 0, child.getLayoutParams());
    }
}
```

This method will work only in sub-classes of **android.view.ViewGroup** class, because it uses protected methods.

The main idea is to move your child view to the first place in child list, because ViewGroup uses natural order of it child's to draw them, which means first view in list will have lowest Z-order, and last view will have highest Z-order.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below :

```
private void moveToBack(View currentView) {
    ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup) currentView.getParent());
    for(int i=0;i<vg.getChildCount();i++){
        View v=vg.getChildAt(i);
        if(!v.equals(currentView))
        {
            vg.bringChildToFront(v);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to bring another child to front.
if you need to make it to extreme back, remove the "break;".

Comment: This  is very "heavy" solution, it uses lots of unnecessary operations with list childs.

Comment: I dont think that. It is just fetching another child and bringing it to front. Did you know how findViewById is working? it is also doing these kind of looping I guess. In your detaching and attaching method, the android system is running loop to find the view for detaching and then the position for attaching it again

Comment: In order to actually move some child to back (I mean give it lowest Z-order), you need to remove "break" from your code, and in that case your code become very "heavy" - it will call bringChildToFront() for every other view in a list.

I suggest simplest solution - just 1 operation, move our view to the beginning of a list.

Comment: I agree with you its a simple operation from your end...but when you attach a view with a position, it is doing the same kind of rearranging inside I guess. For example, in a Array, if we need to insert a value at position 3, we need to move the elements from 3 onwards one step ahead. Also...I'm telling you...its my guess. If that so..in your case...for detaching, there will be a loop inside, attaching also there will be a loop inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
mLastIndex = ((ViewGroup)getParent()).indexOfChild(this);


before you call bringChildToFront,you can record the mLastIndex,then you call moveToBack to send view back.


private void moveToBack(View currentView) {
    ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup) currentView.getParent());
    for(int i = 0; i<viewGroup.getChildCount() - (mLastIndex+1); i++) {
        LogUtils.d(TAG,viewGroup.getChildAt(mLastIndex)+"");
        viewGroup.bringChildToFront(viewGroup.getChildAt(mLastIndex));

    }
}
```